# Geometry Nodes - dynamic vertices count of mesh / Error: vertices must be at least 1

Tags: geometry-nodes

UPDATE:
So I have tried to follow the insctructions posted in the comments but ran into the problem that Blender 3.1 doesn't seem to have "Duplicate Elements"-node. I am still running into the problem that I can't randomize the socket for "count" in the "Mesh Line"-node.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

[image]
[image]

OLD POST:

I have been stuck for the whole afternoon now and I hope that someone has a clue how to solve my problem.

I want the number of vertices to go up with the scale of a mesh object generated in geometry nodes. Application: the cube scales on the z axis, is suppsed to be a building and with each step of scaling, one addition vertex on the Z-axis should be added.

When setting the vertices count as fixed, the result is fine.
[image]

But once I take a random integer value between 1 and 5 and add another integer value and connect this into the vertices count of the mesh, Blender states that the value is supposed to be at least 1.
[image]
As you can see, the result of the math operation "add" should always return an integer greater than 12 in this case.

But I keep getting this error. I habe already tried to add a "Float to Integer" after the math node. Doesn't help either.

Any suggestions?
Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: in Random Value node try to connect a value to your ID input, this will give you the stable random values you need for this property...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real is problem is not that you need an integer instead of a float, but that the *Random Value* node's output is a *field* (diamond-shaped socket), whereas the *Cube* node only accepts a single value (circular socket). A *field* means that a number is not decided ahead of time, but produced dynamically in response to a context. *Cube* is not designed to change its number of vertices dynamically based on context, it (like all other "primitive" objects available in GeoNodes) is meant to be a static object, with set parameters. Now, you can force the *Random Value* node to give you a single value, by providing it with a context (in this case, and ID number), like this:

[image]

There is a problem though: it is giving you a random number (here, 4.xxx), but from this point onward, that number will always be the same. It won't change dynamically based on context, because its context is fixed (ID:22). If you were to distribute this cube, by instancing it on a line for instance, all cubes would have the same amount of vertices. That number would have been determined "randomly" at the start, but it wouldn't change with each copy:

[image]

In that case you'd need to follow another strategy. Instead of trying to vary the number of vertices of your cubes and use them as whole buildings, duplicating them  in the Z direction a random number of times as flats of your buildings, for example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton for this very detailed explanation! I now know that I tackled this completely wrong from the start - not knowing of these limitations. I will now rethinkg this with the guidance you have given and build a new node tree. Again, thanks a ton! That has been rather frustrating tonight!

Comment: Well, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work that way in Blender 3.1 anymore, since the "duplicate elements" node is missing. I tried to find an alternative way but ran into the same diamond-shape vs. round-shape problem. Will post pictures in and edited version of my post.

Comment: Ah, sorry, *Duplicate Elements* is actually a new node. I use 3.2 Alpha. It was just an example so I didn't think to warn about that.

Comment: Will load the Alpha then :-)

Comment: Here's a stream video where Johnny Matthews (the developer of the Duplicate Elements and many other nodes) himself explains and plays with the node: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iefeY2lRSO8 He also has other Geometry Nodes 101-style videos where he goes through the basics, so check him out.